# What is the frequency of a single photon?

Tags: photons, frequency

What frequency means for a single photon?

Comment: It is the rate at which the electrical (or magnetic) vector changes direction. Or it is a measure of the energy. What do you think the answer should be?

Comment: The vector don't change a single photon has one peak that is a half-period (T) T=1/frequency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the very well-known, which is also determines the *Planck constant* too:

$$f=\frac{E}{h}$$

Here $h$ is the Planck-constant, around $6.6*10^{-34} \frac{J}{s}$.

If you have mass, you can convert this to energy by the well known $E=mc^2$ formula.

Comment: No ,you cannot do that with $E=mc^2$ ,rather you should use $E=pc$.a photon cannot have mass.

Comment: Why photon has to not have mass instead of a relativistic formula to be wrong?

Comment: You can use $E=mc^2$ for a photon, since according to Einstein mass and energy are equivalent. The _rest_ mass is zero, though.

Comment: Indeed, the relativistic form is $E^2 = (mc^2)^2 + (pc)^2$, and since rest mass is zero, it simplifies to $E = pc$.

Answer (score 1):

Frequency is inversely proportional to the wavelength of the photon and so in another way of indicating the energy of the photon. Remember that for a given wavelength/frequency, your photon will have a specific energy given by
$$E = \text{a constant} \times \text{frequency} = \frac{\text{a constant}}{\text{wavelength}}$$ All these values measure the same thing.